# Copy lines from one file and paste it to other n times

Tags: awk

I have two files such as the following:

```
file1

t=10
HELLO
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
END
t=20
HELLO
EEEEEE
FFFFFF
GGGGGG
HHHHHH
END

file2

HELLO
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
111111
222222
333333
END
HELLO
EEEEEE
FFFFFF
GGGGGG
HHHHHH
444444
555555
666666
END
```

Is it possible to copy the t=10 and t=20 which are over of HELLO and paste them to the exact location at file2 making it like

```
t=10
HELLO
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
111111
222222
333333
END
t=20
HELLO
EEEEEE
FFFFFF
GGGGGG
HHHHHH
444444
555555
666666
END
```

Of course my files are not so small and imagine that I would like to do this over 100000 times in a file

With the help of other members of the community I created this script but it doesn't give the right result

```
for frame in $(seq 1 1 2)
do
add=$(awk '/t=/{i++}i=='$frame' {print; exit}' $file1)

awk -v var="$add" 'NR>1 && NR%9==0 {print var} {print $0}' $file2

done
```

Please if anyone can help my I could appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script. It reads `file1` and saves each line before the `HELLO` one in an indexed array and extract each position of it when it finds again the line `HELLO` in the second file:

```
awk '
    NR == 1 { prev_line = $0 }
    FNR == NR {
        if ( $1 == "HELLO" ) {
            hash[ i++ ] = prev_line
        }
        prev_line = $0
        next
    }
    $1 == "HELLO" {
        printf "%s\n", hash[ j++ ]
    }
    { print }
' file1 file2
```

It yields:

```
t=10
HELLO
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
111111
222222
333333
END
t=20
HELLO
EEEEEE
FFFFFF
GGGGGG
HHHHHH
444444
555555
666666
END
```

Comment: I think that the main idea is what i want but I cannot save it to a file and it does't apply for bigger files such as files which between HELLO and END are 10000 lines!!! I will try to edit it as much as i can! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="END\n"}
   NR==FNR{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1]=a[$1]==""?$i:a[$1] FS $i;next}
   {for (i in a) {if ($0~a[i]) printf i ORS $0 RS}
   }' file1 file2
```

Result:

```
t=10
HELLO
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
111111
222222
333333
END
t=20
HELLO
EEEEEE
FFFFFF
GGGGGG
HHHHHH
444444
555555
666666
END
```